# upper case and lower case in xml.value

Tags: sql, xml, t-sql

I have two xml versions, renaming the "Serie" and "serie"
Is there a way to just have one query?

```
SELECT Top 10 folioF,  
XMLCFDI.value('(./*:Comprobante/@Serie)[1]','varchar(25)') AS serie
FROM [Comprobantes].[dbo].[CFDI]

SELECT Top 10 folioF,  
XMLCFDI.value('(./*:Comprobante/@serie)[1]','varchar(25)') AS serie
FROM [Comprobantes].[dbo].[CFDI]
```

Comment: Can't you use `Union All`?

Comment: Would repeat the information

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check these approaches with a `.nodes()` call on the attribute's list:

```
DECLARE @xml XML=
N'<root>
<test serie="lower"/>
<test Serie="camel"/>
<test SERIE="upper"/>
<test Other="Other"/>
</root>';

SELECT attr.value('.','nvarchar(max)') AS attrVal
      ,attr.value('local-name(.)','nvarchar(max)') AS attrName
FROM @xml.nodes('/root/test') AS A(tst)
CROSS APPLY tst.nodes('@*') AS B(attr)
```

Alternatively you might limit the results with a predicate (change the last line):

```
CROSS APPLY tst.nodes('@*[lower-case(local-name())="serie"]') AS B(attr)
```

Another approach

```
SELECT tst.value('(./@*[lower-case(local-name())="serie"])[1]','nvarchar(max)')
FROM @xml.nodes('/root/test') AS A(tst)
```